# Automatic folder synchronization to a specific USB drive

Tags: unity, 14.04, sync

I am using [grsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grsync) for folder synchronisation with my usb drive. I usually synchronize folders manually. Now I wish them to happen themselves. So, Is it possible to synchronize folders automatically whenever my usb drive gets mounted?

Comment: +1 I have the same need. Too bad this question has no answers.